# IR with indri - how to get smoothing values and documents data by index

Tags: information-retrieval, indri

I have an index (I didn't build it so I don't have the documents) and I want to get this values from the index:
1. What are the documents the index are based on? and what is their length?
2. Can I get the bag of words values for each document? I know I can get the values for all the corpus with RunQuery_tfidf.xml but I want the values for each document.
3. Is there a way to get the smoothing **values**?